# Boost Hana any_of?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

So I tried to use Boost Hana's any_of method, but unlike the description in the implementation, it still calls the element after the element that first satisfied the predicate. Is this a know bug ?

Here is an [MCVE](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0XW2wsxoyqfxHzYA):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

int main() {
    auto t = boost::hana::tuple_t<int, double, float>;
    boost::hana::any_of(t, [](auto) { std::cout << "Called\n"; return true; });
}
```

Output:

```
Called
Called
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Nothing in the documentation says it won't be applied to multiple elements, even if one of them satisfies the predicate. Reading the implementation, the behavior matches what I'd expect. Though I can agree it may be counter-intuitive and would personally have done it differently, statements with side-effects in a predicate is also generally frowned upon.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1detail_1_1any__of.html

Comment: @Yamahari This is `hana::detail::any_of`, not `hana::any_of`.

Comment: Oh yea, Oppsies. But isn't this still a weird behaviour or is there no other way to implement it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug; thanks for finding it. The predicate was always evaluated one more time than strictly necessary. The bug is fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/commit/a39d2fb90c32b65d72acf4ed994c4a12e5608e10), which will make its way into Boost 1.64.0.

**That being said**, Hana's documentation specifically forbids you from relying on this (and also having side effects in the functions you send to algorithms): http://boostorg.github.io/hana/#tutorial-algorithms-effects. So, while I consider it a bug from a performance perspective, it is not a bug strictly speaking since it does not break the contract given to you by the library.

The reason why I can't make this part of the contract of the function is that it might prevent some implementation strategies from being valid, and I want to keep this liberty. I would consider it more seriously if the use case was compelling, but it does not seem to be.